# Mockito: verifify invocation with a argument of a given class

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I need to write the following assert statement:

```
verify(tp, never()).addEvent(eventOfTypeA);
```

It should fail when addEvent is invoked, but only if it is invoked only with a TypeAEvent as parameter. 
I also tried:

```
verify(tp, never()).addEvent((TypeAEvent) any());
```

but it doesn't work.

I know that that I can set a captor, get all events given as parameters and then check each of them using instanceOf(), but I think that is an ugly solution. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you share tp's interface please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try

```
verify(tp, never()).addEvent(isA(TypeAEvent.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
verify(tp, never()).addEvent(Matchers.any(TypeAEvent.class));
```